# How to find each <a> tag in a string and replcae url with absolute url

Tags: jquery

I am getting HTML of a `div` using `jQuery` in a variable outHTML. How to  replace `href` of all anchor tags with `absolute URI` outHTML. Please suggest how to do this.

```
 var outHTML = $("#center_div").html();

$("#center_div a").attr('href', function (i, href) {

    var Check = href.split('/');

});
```

Comment: not getting you question...

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming that the absolute URL is always the same domain and root prefix, you could just do:

```
var root = 'http://www.example.com/';
$('#center_div a').attr('href', function(i, href) {  
    return root + href
});
```

See this [**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5JhdQ/)

Comment: +1 but you'd probably have to do a check to see if the links already have a http at the start in-case the div contains any external site links

Answer (score 0):

```
var outHTML = $("#center_div").html();

$("#center_div a").each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href','Your absolute path here');
});
```